# How to get base element in polymer 2.0?

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I am currently working on Polymer 2.0.
Previously I used 1.7.0. In that we used domHost or dataHost to get base element.
Like this -

```
 this.domHost.querySelector("#paperCard");
```

But in polymer 2.0 it's not working.
Any suggestions for this.

**Update**

My flow of elements is somethink like this -

search-element  -->  card-element --> form-element

This is a property from form-element which is calling label from index -

```
childAgeLabel: {
                    type: String,
                    value: function () {
                        var labelChildAge = this.dataHost.dataHost.domHost.domHost.child;
                        return labelChildAge;
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use
`this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#paperCard')`

but even "nicer" would probably be
`this.$.paperCard`

this.$ lets you select your shadow dom element if it has an id.

Comment: you are correct but in property value function it does not working